# Best way to get the sticky effect (artsy.net)

Tags: css, sticky

I'm pretty new to advanced CSS and I'm currently working on my personal website.
I'd like to have a big picture on the front page then when you scroll it get covered by the rest of the page (please see : http://artsy.net/) 
I'm fair new to this and i'd like to now what's the best way to achieve this effect...
I know there are some plugins to achieve this (http://davist11.github.io/jQuery-Stickem/) but i'm not sure it's the best way to do it.

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

try this css for the image:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

then for the rest of the page use a wrapper div:

```
margin-top:300px;
background:#FFF;
```

that should solve the "sticky" issue, and let the rest of the page scroll over the image. You can assign it to an image or a whole div as you like.